# Is naming your son "Abd" allowed for Muslims?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

Salam, is it permissible to name my son Abd (with nothing preceding or following it)?

Comment: Abd mean Slave, generally. It's better name him Abd Allah. like other names such as Habib Allah.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the permissibility of naming Abd (with nothing preceding or following), I've never read any Hadith stating that it is not permissible to use this name. However, it's always been a common practice in Arabia, even before Islam, to add a name after Abd, like Abd Manaf, etc... In KSA and some other Gulf countries, they use it with the definite article Alif Laam, Al-Abd, which means The Slave, or The Servant. But if you use it without Al, the name will then have a different meaning that's not correct, for instance, Abd Muhammad (Slave of Muhammad)

Indeed, Allah know the best.

Comment: Uh, yeah. you are right as you remarked: I've never read any Hadith stating that it is not permissible to use this name. However, it's always been a common practice in Arabia, even before Islam, to add a name after Abd.

Answer (score 2):

In Islam naming a child should be done with care. The name must mean something good. Abdallah, Abd-ur-Rahman are  some good examples. But naming your son just Abd literally means slave. It may not be recommended to do so. Also consider his future when people might  harass him calling him a slave.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct to name 'Abd' because it means 'Slave' with 'Al' or without.

And because 'Slave' has no good means.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must choose a good name for your baby that's stay with him throughout his life not cause him some embarrassment
2. The best names starts with Abd ( Abd Allah , Abd Al rahman , Abd..any name of Allah names), and the names of Mohammed,Ahmed, taha, Mahmoud or the names of Prophets.
3. Name Abd mean slave